# MDL Modal Dialog click behind modal background

Tags: javascript, css, material-design-lite

I have created a modal dialog using Material Design Lite from https://getmdl.io/components/#dialog-section. But I'm facing a problem that the area outside the dialog is not clickable.

I have a logout button outside the modal which I want the user to click when he wants to logout. Also, I do not want to hide the modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dialog = document.querySelector('#main-dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    dialog.showModal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="main-dialog">
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Select your .xlsx file:</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
        <p>
            Your excel sheet must contain values in the form:<br/>
            <table border="1" style="margin:0 auto">
                <tr>
                    <td><font color="black"><b>PID No.</b></font></td>
                    <td><font color="black"><b>Student Name</b></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
       <input id="list" type="file" required="yes" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
    </div>
</dialog>
```

How can I make the background of the modal clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the Dialog background clickable use `dialog.show();` instead of `dialog.showModal();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dialog = document.querySelector('#main-dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
            dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    dialog.show();
});
```

See [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJgKmx)

---

From MDL Docs:

> ```
> button.addEventListener('click', function() {
>    dialog.showModal();
>    /* Or dialog.show(); to show the dialog without a backdrop. */   
> });
> ```

Comment: I check your code on codepen. But when I try it, the dialog doesn't appear at all when I use this code, although the button is clickable.

Comment: Fork my codepen and try to reproduce the problem. As you can see its your own code that I use so its weird... It might be another js/css that breaks your code.. do you have any console errors? It should work for you...

Comment: Working, it was some problem with the MDL classes I had used in parent elements. Thank You!